# Calculating when Lambda Layers should be updated

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline, aws-lambda-layers

I have a project with a CodePipeline sourcing from Github which updates layers based on file changes. We don't want to automatically update the layers on every commit because they are not necessarily changing. Because there is no built-in comparison with lambda layers to be updated, the burden of determining if a layer should be updated falls to the user. I've tried a couple different options:

1. Hash the local representation of the layer files and compare it to the most recent lambda layer on AWS. If the hash is different, you know you have file changes, and should update.
2. Look at your git file changes (i.e. with PythonGit) and see if any of your layers have changed files. If so, you should update your layer.

2 is a problem in CodePipeline specifically because when a repo is sourced from github, the `Download Zip` functionality is used, not git clone, so the .git folder is removed. You could get it back via renaming it, but it gets messy.

I'd be interested to hear how other people have handled this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write some version/hash/etc to the description of the Lambda Layer.
You can compare this description with the version in your git.

It sounds a little bit creepy, so I prefer to build layer every time I commit to master (for example), and automatically delete previous versions (saving last N versions for potential rollback).

It's not so overhead for my purposes, but it depends on your issue.

Comment: That's a very good idea to save the hashing to the lambda layer. I was doing it all on the fly before. We have a pipeline with many people working on it, so the versioning is a little much for what we need.